# Trigger mouseleave when over a child

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, hover

I am stuck on something that is probably really easy to solve but i can't manage to do it. I want the style of my parent to change when i hover it but go back to normal when I hover a child of parent.

**html:**

```
<div id="parent">
   <div id="child"></div>
</div>
```

**Js/jQuery:**

```
$('#parent').on({
    mouseenter: function (event) {
        event.stopPropagation();
        event.stopImmediatePropagation();
        $(this).css("box-shadow", "inset 0 0 0 1000px green");
    },
    mouseleave: function (event) {
        event.stopPropagation();
        event.stopImmediatePropagation();
        $(this).css("box-shadow", "inset 0 0 0 0px pink");
    }
});
```

**Fiddle:**

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/o0a71Lpr/1/)

Comment: If you hover over the child after the parent,I guess you have not actually left the parent. You might need to write the `mouseleave` code in the child.mouseenter event as well as the parent.mouseleave

Comment: Mouse out does the trick to going back but when leaving the child again it doesn't trigger the mouse enter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use mouseover and mouseout and detect what element is triggering in on mouseover.

```js
$('#parent').on({
  mouseover: function(event) {
    if (!$(this).is(event.target)) return;
    event.stopPropagation();
    event.stopImmediatePropagation();
    $(this).css("box-shadow", "inset 0 0 0 1000px green");
  },
  mouseout: function(event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
    event.stopImmediatePropagation();
    $(this).css("box-shadow", "inset 0 0 0 0px pink");
  }
});
```

```css
#parent {
  background-color: pink;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}
#child {
  position: relative;
  left: 75px;
  top: 75px;
  background-color: blue;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="parent">
  <div id="child"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: You are right this looks a lot cleaner ill accept it as answer when i can! thanks you

Answer (score 0):

RiggsFolly comment worked changed the JS to this:

```
$('#parent').on({
    mouseenter: function (event) {
        event.stopPropagation();
        event.stopImmediatePropagation();
        $(this).css("box-shadow", "inset 0 0 0 1000px green");
    },
    mouseout: function (event) {
        event.stopPropagation();
        event.stopImmediatePropagation();
        $(this).css("box-shadow", "inset 0 0 0 0px pink");
    }        
});
$('#child').on({
    mouseenter: function (event) {
        event.stopPropagation();
        event.stopImmediatePropagation();
        $("#parent").css("box-shadow", "inset 0 0 0 0px green");
    },
    mouseleave: function (event) {
        event.stopPropagation();
        event.stopImmediatePropagation();
        $("#parent").css("box-shadow", "inset 0 0 0 1000px green");
    }
});
```

And it works now thanks Riggs!